# RTCMultiConnection how to get started

Tags: php, socket.io, npm, webrtc

I installed the RTCMultiConnection from : https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection

I have a dedicated hosting with linux computer.

• I followed the instructions, downloaded and installed RTCMultiConnection in the public_html.

• I also downloaded and installed socket.io created a folder "socket.io" and put socket.io.js in it.

• I also started `"node __path_to_node_modules/rtcmulticonnection-v3/server.js"`

*** I'm stuck there... when I go to `https://__mydomain__.com:9001/` it says 
"404 Not Found: /"

*** I the folder "socket.io" I created a empty index.html (if not ; the log says 403 forbidden...)

••••• Do I need something else in the folder "socket.io" ?

When I go to https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Video-Conferencing.html I'm able to create a room and joining it in a other browser.

but when I to to `https://___mydomain____.com/demos/Video-Conferencing.html` I can create a room but unable to join with an other browser...

Can someone tell me what step I miss

Thanks

Comment: When you try to join with an another browser using the link `https://___mydomain____.com/demos/Video-Conferencing.html` on the server console what error comes?

Comment: That's why I'm stuck. I don't see erros...

Comment: Okay. Can you either paste the browser console log when you try to join or compare the same log when you use `https://___mydomain____.com/demos/Video-Conferencing.html` and `https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Video-Conferencing.html`.

Comment: @JohnR Please use this command: `cd __path_to_node_modules/rtcmulticonnection-v3 && node server.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should download TAR that has everything (`socket.io@0.9.17`) included:

- [rtcmulticonnection-v3.tar.gz](http://dl.webrtc-experiment.com/rtcmulticonnection-v3.tar.gz)

Or `wget` the TAR:

```
mkdir RTCMultiConnection-v3.0 && cd RTCMultiConnection-v3.0
wget http://dl.webrtc-experiment.com/rtcmulticonnection-v3.tar.gz
tar -zxvf rtcmulticonnection-v3.tar.gz
ls -a
```

#### Please don't forget to go to `server.js` directory (*it is required*):

```
cd RTCMultiConnection-v3.0
ls -a
```

And now everything will/should work:

```
node server.js
```

and open: `https://localhost:9001/`

Comment: Thanks !!!!! ;) it's the last part... I did  : 
••••1••••• cd path_to_node_modules/rtcmulticonnection-v3/     
•••••2••••• node server.js    ••••• 
than When I go to https://___mydomain____.com:9001/ everything works like a charm ;)

Comment: I got it to work, but unable to "Keep running server in background..." from the instructions : "nohup nodejs server.js > /dev/null 2>&1 &" does nothing.

Comment: @JohnR You can either use `nohup` command e.g. `nohup nodejs server.js &` or try forever-module e.g. `npm instlal forever -g && forever start server.js` - PS. You can check your `node.js` version using `node --version` A few systems may use alias `nodejs` rather than `node` which means you have to execute: `nohup nodejs server.js &`

Comment: Thanks, the forever command works but what about make it work at boot ?

Comment: I didn't try following links myself yet however `forever-service` claims same thing (i.e. auto-restart-on-system-reboot): https://github.com/zapty/forever-service You can even check another alternative `node-startup`: https://github.com/chovy/node-startup

Comment: Is threre a way to make server.js redirect to a index.php ? I  tried, But I see the code instead of the result

Comment: Did you meant `response.writeHead(301, {"Location": "http://example.com/page.php"});`?

Comment: no, a index.php that will have $_Get, and Other stuff... (like control access with logins and stuff).

Comment: It's ok, I was able to add jquery and do $.ajax calls ;)

Answer (score 1):

After getting the server up and running on a different port than 80 (thanks to forever-service https://github.com/zapty/forever-service)

In terminal :

```
1- cd __path to your npm install__    
2- forever-service install ncustomAppName --script server.js
```

> Commands to interact with service ncustomAppName Start
>   - "sudo
>   service **ncustomAppName** start" Stop
>   - "sudo service
>   **ncustomAppName** stop" Status
>   - "sudo service **ncustomAppName** status" Restart 
>   - "sudo service **ncustomAppName** restart"

---

Here the code on regular https://__MyDomain.com/ (( https needed here for webrtc ))

```
<div id="videos-container"></div>

<script src="js/rmc3.min.js').'"></script>
<script src="js/socket.io.js').'"></script>

<script>  

var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
connection.socketURL = "https://__MyDomain.com:9000/"; //or the port you choose creating the forever-service...
var roomid = "main_room";

connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};

var videosContainer = document.getElementById("videos-container");
connection.onstream = function(event) {
    videosContainer.appendChild(event.mediaElement);
    setTimeout(function() { event.mediaElement.play();  }, 5000);
};

connection.openOrJoin(roomid);

</script>
```